# Assigning a vector to a matrix column in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

*This question was asked in haste.* The error in my original program, was not the typo in the code that is displayed here. The error was that in my program v was not getting populated due to some conditions.

The more useful takeaway from this thread is the demonstration of copying a std::vector to all rows or columns of an Eigen Matrix, in the accepted answer.

---

I want to copy vectors into the columns of a matrix, like the following:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int m = 10;
   
    std::vector<Eigen::VectorXd> v(m);
    Eigen::MatrixXd S(m,m);
   
    for (int i = 0; i != m; ++i) {
        v[i].resize(m);
        for (int j = 0; j != m; ++j) {
            v[i](j) = rand() % m;
        }
        //S.cols(i) = v[i]; //needed something like this
    }

    return 0;
}
```

S is of type Eigen::MatrixXd and dimension mxm. v is a std::vector of Eigen::VectorXd, where each Eigen::VectorXd is of size m and there are m of them in v.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regarding the original question, you need to wrap the `std::vector` with an `Eigen::Map`. You could/should also make the operation a one-liner.

The reworded question is reduced to a typo. `S.cols(i)` should be `S.col(i)`.

```
int main()
{
    size_t sz = 6;
    Eigen::MatrixXd S(sz, sz);
    std::vector<double> v(sz);
    std::vector<Eigen::VectorXd> vv(sz);
    for(int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
    {
        v[i] = i*2;
        vv[i] = Eigen::VectorXd::LinSpaced(sz, (i+sz), (i+sz)*2);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i != sz; ++i)
        S.col(i) = vv[i];
    std::cout << S << "\n\n";

    S.rowwise() = Eigen::Map<Eigen::RowVectorXd>(v.data(), sz);
    std::cout << S << "\n\n";

    S.colwise() = Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd>(v.data(), sz);
    std::cout << S << "\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

which would output

> 6    7    8    9   10   11
>    7.2  8.4  9.6 10.8   12 13.2
>    8.4  9.8 11.2 12.6   14 15.4
>    9.6 11.2 12.8 14.4   16 17.6
>   10.8 12.6 14.4 16.2   18 19.8
>     12   14   16   18   20   22
>
> 0  2  4  6  8 10
>    0  2  4  6  8 10
>    0  2  4  6  8 10
>    0  2  4  6  8 10
>    0  2  4  6  8 10
>    0  2  4  6  8 10
>
> 0  0  0  0  0  0
>    2  2  2  2  2  2
>    4  4  4  4  4  4
>    6  6  6  6  6  6
>    8  8  8  8  8  8
>   10 10 10 10 10 10

Comment: There was an issue in displaying the type of v. Please, check the edit. I want to copy unique VectorXd's to each column of a MatrixXd.

Comment: That is why creating and posting a [mcve] makes things easier on the asker and answerer.